# hbase export row size limit

Tags: backup, hbase

I want to create a backup of my hbase table using hbase export.
The problem is that my rows are very big and I get a java heap space error. Is there any parameter I can give in order to limit the copied size in each step?

I use the following command:

`hadoop   jar   /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.90.3-cdh3u1.jar   export   tableName   backupPathOnHdfs   numberOfColumnFamiliesVersions`

or

`hbase   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export   tableName backupPathOnHdfs   numberOfColumnFamiliesVersions`

Comment: can you show us codes you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the export tool, that is, `hadoop jar hbase-*-SNAPSHOT.jar export`, with a regexp param (if it starts with `^`) or interpreted as a row key prefix as the last argument. Details see in the [source](http://hbase.apache.org/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/Export.html#172) as it seems not yet to be [documented](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#export) (should work from 0.91.0 on).